# SMS verification with React Native for Both Android and IOS

Tags: react-native

I am trying to do sms verification through react native where an OTP will be sent to a provided number. It worked when I was doing it normally in react native following this example https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms-android but in expo project its not working. Though the package only works for android , I want a solution which will work for both android and ios.

I have also tried the following package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-send-sms

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms-android only supports android. If you need to work on ios then you have to use LinkingIOS in react-native and call sms app. It's a bit headache.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-send-sms is depricated.

You can use [this](https://github.com/tkporter/react-native-sms) to send SMS in both android and ios.

Comment: I have tried using the package you suggested but it didn't work. May be I missed something. But does it work on the project created by expo?